# JQuery selector to match table having N rows

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I have a div with two tables.  I want to select the rows from only the one table having N rows.

In XPath I would use:

```
//div[@class="div1"]/table[count(tr) = 2]/tr
```

Is there a jQuery selector expression that will do the same thing?

Here's the HTML snippet:

```
<div>
  <div class="div1">
    <ul>
      <li>Line 1</li>
    </ul>
    <ul>
      <li>Line 1</li>
      <li>Line 2</li>
    </ul>
  </div>      
</div>
```

I was hoping this could be done in a single jQuery selector expression (e.g., understood in this [Interactive JQuery Tester](http://sk.kapsi.fi/interactive-jquery-tester.html) ).   My starting point is:

```
'div.div1 ul li'
```

but that also selects the rows from the first table which only has 1 row.

Of course, the "right way" to do this is add IDs or something else to the HTML so that the table can be identified uniquely, however in this instance I have no control over the HTML I am grabbing the data from.  The only way I can tell which of the multiple tables to use is from the row count.

Comment: Obviously, my html snippet is not for a <table>.  Ooops.  Copied and pasted from the wrong source. Anyway, the answer I selected is correct in that the same approach be used to select rows of a table just as well as it does selecting lines from a list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can do this with a single jQuery selector.

In your case you could just combine the [`:has()` selector](https://api.jquery.com/has-selector/), the [`:eq()` selector](https://api.jquery.com/eq-selector/), and the [`:last-child` pseudo class](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:last-child) in order to select a `ul` element that has two `li` children elements. Keep in mind that the `:eq()` selector accepts an index that is zero-based (which means that we would use an index of `1` in order to select the second `li` element). The `:last-child` pseudo class is then used in order to ensure that the second `li` is in fact the last child element.

```
$('.div1 ul:has(li:eq(1):last-child)')
```

Snippet:

```js
$('.div1 ul:has(li:eq(1):last-child)').addClass('selected');
```

```css
.selected { color: #f00; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div>
  <div class="div1">
    <ul>
      <li>Line 1</li>
    </ul>
    <ul>
      <li>Line 1</li>
      <li>Line 2</li>
    </ul>
    <ul>
      <li>Line 1</li>
      <li>Line 2</li>
      <li>Line 3</li>
    </ul>
  </div>      
</div>
```

---

Alternatively, you could also utilize the [`:nth-child()` pseudo class](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child) as well.

```
$('.div1 ul:has(li:nth-child(2):last-child)')
```

Snippet:

```js
$('.div1 ul:has(li:nth-child(2):last-child)').addClass('selected');
```

```css
.selected { color: #f00; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div>
  <div class="div1">
    <ul>
      <li>Line 1</li>
    </ul>
    <ul>
      <li>Line 1</li>
      <li>Line 2</li>
    </ul>
    <ul>
      <li>Line 1</li>
      <li>Line 2</li>
      <li>Line 3</li>
    </ul>
  </div>      
</div>
```